# How to specify reference lifetime for trait implementation?

Tags: rust

How to implement **TraitFoo** for **struct Foo**?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'f> {
    os: Option<&'f str>
}

impl<'f> Foo<'f> {
    fn new(x: &'f str) -> Foo<'f> {
        Foo {
            os:Some(x)
        }       
    }
}

trait TraitFoo {
    fn foo(x:&str) -> Self;
}

impl<'f> TraitFoo for Foo<'f> {
    fn foo(x: &str) -> Foo<'f> {
        Foo {
            os:Some(x)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Foo::new("one"));
    println!("{:?}", Foo::foo("two"));
}
```

The code above fails with error:

```
lf_trait.rs:21:12: 21:13 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements
lf_trait.rs:21          os:Some(x)

lf_trait.rs:19:2: 23:3 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn foo(x: &'f str) -> Foo<'f>
lf_trait.rs:19  fn foo(x:&str) -> Foo<'f> {
lf_trait.rs:20      Foo{
lf_trait.rs:21          os:Some(x)
lf_trait.rs:22      }
lf_trait.rs:23  }
```

Using lifetime `'f` in the function `fn foo(x:&'f str) -> Foo<'f>` gives other error:

```
lf_trait.rs:19:2: 23:3 error: method `foo` has an incompatible type for trait: expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime [E0053]
lf_trait.rs:19  fn foo(x:&'f str) -> Foo<'f> {
lf_trait.rs:20      Foo{
lf_trait.rs:21          os:Some(x)
lf_trait.rs:22      }
lf_trait.rs:23  }
```

Is there any way to implement `TraitFoo` for `Foo`?

---

About purposes:

I tried to create my own error class with specified position where error appear. I need similar trait to convert standard errors to my error:

```
pub trait FromWhere<'a,T>:std::convert::From<T> {
    fn from_where(T, &'a str) -> Self;
}

impl<'e,T:ApplyWrpErrorTrait+std::convert::From<T>+'static> FromWhere<'e,T> for WrpError<'e> {
  fn from_where(err: T, whr:&'e str) -> WrpError<'e> {
      if whr!="" {
          WrpError{
              kind: ErrorKind::Wrapped,
              descr: None,
              pos: Some(whr),
              cause: Some(Box::new(err))
          }
      }else{
          std::convert::From::from(err)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this trait?

Comment: It is just for example, nothing more.

Comment: Can't add code here, so i am edit question to answer to @sellibitze comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the lifetime on the trait, too.

```
trait TraitFoo<'a> {
    fn foo(x: &'a str) -> Self;
}

impl<'a> TraitFoo<'a> for Foo<'a> {
    fn foo(x:&'a str) -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo{
            os:Some(x)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of a generic function that makes use of this trait?